# Why I can't submit or validate project in Archives organizer (XCode)?

Tags: xcode, app-store, xcode-organizer

Today I finish one old project, the application work fine without any errors or warnings, the project is started with Xcode 4.3 modifed with 4.5, 5.0, and now finished and compiled with Xcode 6.0 and everything works.

The problem is that I can't sumbmit it to AppStore, the buttons in Archives organizer are disabled, there is different type of archive and icon.

But with new project all work, and I can submit it without any problem.

snapshot:
[image]

Exist any solution or I need to re-write all code in a new project ?

Comment: I think your archive is damaged, have you tried to re-archive?

Comment: Yes about 40 times with diferent settings, but nothing, I thing maybe there is some difference in old project files and new procject created with new Xcode version or this is a bug in  Archives organizer ??